# Is there a way to change my placeholder to just read the display name attribute of my model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there a way to change my placeholder to just read the display name attribute of my model?

Currently I have this line of code.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Address1, new { @class = "form-control text-center", @placeholder = "Address Line 1" })
```

I would prefer the placeholder to just use the displayname attribute that I have in my model.

```
[Display(Name = "Address Line 1")]
public string Address1 { get; set; }
```

Revision:
Tried but not getting placeholder to show.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Address1, new { @class = "form-control text-center", @placeholder = ViewData.ModelMetadata.DisplayName })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to do the trick...

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Address1, new { @class = "form-control text-center", @placeholder = @Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.Address1) })
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep your model the same:

```
[Display(Name = "Address Line 1")]
public string Address1 { get; set; }
```

Then create a EditorTemplate for type string, you can do this for any type:

```
@model string

@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x, new { @Placeholder = ViewData.ModelMetadata.DisplayName })
```

And then call your template

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Address1 )
```

Hope this helps.